# React Native Navigation Problems

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and want to be able to make my code where the user clicks on text and it takes them from an initial page and am very confused as to how I am supposed to do this and where to put what. Am I supposed to have separate files for separate pages? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Navigator or NavigatorIOS components are what you're looking for. Basically, your text elements need to be wrapped in an element like TouchableHighlight that has an onPress handler that utilizes the navigator.push() to navigate. Or you could j[This tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/using-navigators.html) does a pretty good job describing how Navigation works on a basic level within React Native apps.

As to separate files for separate pages - it's not necessary, but as you develop your own custom components and your apps become more complicated, having them in separate files helps with keeping you

Comment: Ok thank you @zany-cadence if I don't have multiple pages would I create a new class in the index.ios.js and call on that?

Comment: yep, just make sure not to add the "export default" keywords before declaring your component. This is super useful when building complex modules, as you can break out it's functionality into smaller and smaller components, making it much easier to track down issues, and re-use code.